# getting concurrentmodificationexception without doing any replace,remove or add to String array

Tags: java, android

I am getting the concurrentmodificationexception while a for loop is going through a Set. There is no part within code in the for loop that contains remove, add or replace which can lead to this exception. Below is a snippet code (a simplified one of what I have)

```
Configuration config= new Configuration();
Set<String> events = config.getEvents();
String[] evta=null;
for(String evt: events){
   evta=evt.split(";");
   //... using the evta for creating new strings but not adding, removing or modifying the events Set<String>.

}
```

So, I wonder what it might be causing this exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't really tell from the code provided. But is any other part of the program accessing "config.getEvents();"?

Comment: we'll have to see the lines where it's happening

Comment: Plz show us the errorlog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must not* modify the `events` while iterating thru it; to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` you need to use an `Iterator`

```
    Iterator<String> iter = events.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        String item = iter.next();
        if(item.equals(<what>)) {
            iter.remove(); //or split() or whatever.
        }
    }
```

Please show more lines to determine which line in particular causes the modification of the backing array, thus throwing the `ConcurrentModificationException` but using the Iterator will most likely avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for that solution. Using this iterator is helping me avoid the exception.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no part within code in the for loop that contains remove, add or replace which can lead to this exception.

Well, given that the exception is only thrown if something does modify the collection during iteration, that cannot be true.

Some part of your code, somewhere, is modifying that collection:

- Possibly it is another thread.
- Possibly that change is happening in some method called directly or indirectly within the loop.
- Possibly the change is via a different wrapper for the collection.

However, this is all speculation.  If you want an answer that is better than "look again", you will need to show us an MCVE for the problem.